# Getting Javascript To Pass Variable By Value

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6

I have two while loops running simultaneously with observables, the methods look like this (I've taken out the names for brevity):

```
  initiateGraph(fromDate: Date, toDate: Date) {
    const graphParts = zip(
          this.dothefirstthing(fromDate, toDate),
          this.doanotherthing(fromDate, toDate)
    );
  }
```

both methods take the from  and to date and put them into a while loop that looks like this:

```
while(from < to) {

  //do stuff

  from.setMonth(from.getMonth() + 1);
}
```

The problem is, when "doanotherthing" gets run, the code won't enter the while loop because the from and to dates are equal. If I switch the order in the zip, the same thing happens to the other method.

Unless I'm mistaken, this is happening because the from date is being changed by the first while loop and therefore not hitting when the second gets run.

Therefore my first thought was to try and pass the value instead of the reference which was clearly the problem....now I'm not so sure

THINGS I'VE TRIED TO GET AROUND PROBLEM:

1. setting local variables in each method so right above the while loop
2. creating an ImmutableDate class that has a readonly property and setting the dates in initiate graph
3. setting block scoping variables in initiate graph

Why won't these work? And how can I get around this issue?

Comment: See Michael's answer below. For simplicity, you could even do this in both function calls: `this.dothefirstthing(new Date(fromDate), new Date(toDate));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new copy of the date at the beginning of each method.

```
const fromDate = new Date(from)
```

then use this within the loop.

Comment: I think it's even simpler – `const fromDate2 = new Date(fromDate)`

Comment: nice one, simplest I've seen out there